# QT creator: How to open an existing project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

First of all, I apologize if my question is stupid. Although it seems easy, I cannot find a solution.

I am a newbie to Qt creator. I installed it on Linux. And every time I want to open an existing project, I have difficulty. So, when I choose an existing project from the welcome tab, a list of recently created projects is shown. Choosing from this list is straightforward. And when I look at paths, it is something like .../Project_folder/file.pro when the latter is chosen, in the edit tab I will have something as described in Figure 1 where I can have access to the main.cpp file and edit it: [image: Figure 1]

However, when the project is not listed and I must click on "open project" and browse file.pro from the Project_folder, it asks me to "configure project" and "import existing build". I know the build folder with respect to Project_folder is located in ../build_folder. I add manually this path. Now in the edit tab, I have a folder with only the .pro file. So, no access to main.cpp. This is shown in Figure 2 where the second project is HelloWorld: [image: Figure 2]

Now, the question is how to open an existing project in a way that I can edit it. I know it should be very simple, but I can not figure it out.

P.S.: This is the content of HelloWorld.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

Comment: There is a doc. about [Opening Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-opening.html).

Comment: Maybe, there is something wrong with your `HelloWorld.pro`. You could [edit] your question to expose the contents of `HelloWorld.pro` as text.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not stupid, I think everyone who used Qt without following any tutorials may have had this problem, including me.

All my projects created with Qt 6.6 Qt Creator had a file named CMakeLists.txt. Just had to open that file and it contained the paths for the rest of the code files and etc.